# Show other text box based on value entered in the first one using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing some HTML in MVC and have two text boxes in my view. I have to show the weight textbox if age 10 to 30 is entered. If not, then don't show or hide if changed. I'm not sure how to achieve this using jQuery.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <h3>Details</h3>
    </legend>

    <div class="field colon">
        <label>Enter Age</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age, new { @class ="text210" })
    </div>

    <div class="field colon">
        <label>Enter Weight</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Weight, new { @class ="text210" })
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Use a `change` event, then check the value each change./

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jQuery code to hide and show the parent `div` of the weight depending on the age value:

```
$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Age)").on("change", function() {
  if (this.value > 9 && this.value < 31)
    $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Weight)").parent().hide();
  else
    $("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Weight)").parent().show();
});
```

If you want to start with the weight hidden, add this CSS to its `div`:

```
<div class="field colon" style="display: none;">
```

Here is a demo, I converted the ASP code to its HTML equivalent:

```js
$("#Age").on("change", function() {
  if (this.value > 9 && this.value < 31)
    $("#Weight").parent().hide();
  else
    $("#Weight").parent().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <h3>Details</h3>
  </legend>

  <div class="field colon">
    <label>Enter Age</label>
    <input type="text" id="Age" name="age" />
  </div>

  <div class="field colon" style="display: none;">
    <label>Enter Weight</label>
    <input type="text" id="Weight" name="Weight" class="text210" />
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks, what about clearing the weight if a different age is entered out of range?

Comment: Then change the condition to `if (this.value < 10 || this.value > 30)` and replace the three lines after it with `$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Weight)").val("");`. If you want to clear the value in addition to the showing/hiding, then simply add the line `$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.Weight)").val("");` before or after the `hide()` line. You will need to add curved brackets `{ }` to the `if` because it now contains two lines.